# How to replace text with a pattern containing '%' in batch

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have a variable with the text `A%20B` and I would like to transform it into a variable with `A B` by performing string replacement in batch.

I tried the following:

```
set string=A%%20B
set new_string=%string:^%20= %
echo %new_string%
```

But it returns the result `A%20B`.

I also tried the following:

```
set string=A%%20B
set new_string=%string:%%20= %
echo %new_string%
```

But it returns the result `0=`.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

- `enabledelayedexpansion`
- replacing the `%`in the string replacement by `!`

The following would work:

```
set string=A%%20B
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set better_string=!string:%%20= !
echo %better_string%
```

This would return `A B` as desired.